# I'm not afraid "to" you?

Tags: pronunciation, phrasal-verbs

Is "afraid to" ever heard of?
I was watching Iron Man 3 with subtitles. I thought I heard "not afraid to you" but the subtitle shows "not afraid of you". I know that the particle "of" is the norm, but is "to" valid too?

You could listen to the sentence in the first 5 or 7 seconds of this short [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2YVRjqVb28) video.
Do you hear "of" or "to"?

By the way I did a Google search but couldn't find anything interesting.

**Update:** I think the particle "of" is practically dropped in fast speech. So the sentence is heard as: "afraid-[schwa]-you"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your update is right.  It's ***of***, not ***to***.

In this recording, the pronunciation of the unstressed preposition ***of*** is simply /ə/.  The following consonant /v/ is dropped entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Both "of" and "to" can be correct:

1. Be afraid of doing something:

   *Luke is afraid of getting lost*.
2. Be afraid to do something:

   *A lot of people are afraid to fly*.

Comment: But *"I'm afraid to you" is incorrect.